# Proof of existence of a rational curve on a Fano variety with degree bounded, in Debarre's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Debarre's book, Higher-Dimensional Algebraic Geometry. On page 61, we have the following theorem: if $X$ is a Fano variety of dimension $n > 0$, then through any point $x \in X$ there is a rational curve of $(-K_{X})$-degree at most $n + 1$. In the middle of its proof, on page 62, when Debarre explain the reduction to positive characterist, he says: embed $X$ in a projective space and let $R$ be the finitely generated subring of $k$ generated by the coefficients of the polynomial equations defining $X$ and the coordinates of $x$. There is a projective scheme $Y \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and a $R$-point $x_{R}$, such that $X$ is obtained from its generic fiber by base change from the quotient field of $R$ to $k$.

My question is: what is $Y$ and how we get the property presented above?

Thank you!

Comment: $Y$ is the subscheme of $\mathbf P^n_R$ defined by the same equations that define $X$. Doing base change just amounts to letting those equations define a subscheme of $\mathbf P^n_k$ instead, but that just gives back $X$.